# Sort alphabetically categories in list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, kotlin

I have a list with items that have category.

```
enum class ItemCategory {
    ACCOUNT,
    CARD,
    OTHER,
    INVESTMENTS,
    LOAN
}
```

I sort items alphabetically by category:

```
items = itemList.sortedBy { it.category.name }.groupBy { it.category }
```

Output now:
ACCOUNT,
CARD,
INVESTMENTS,
LOAN,
OTHER,
PAYMENT

Expected:
ACCOUNT,
CARD,
INVESTMENTS,
LOAN,
PAYMENT,
OTHER

Comment: You sorted alphabetically by the `category.name` which is giving the correct output as `Other` is alphabetically before `Payment` due to `O` being before `P` in the alphabet.

Comment: Do you really expect PAYMENT before OTHER in an alphabetical order? If you want OTHER to be the last one always, then implement a custom order or use some different word than PAYMENT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Output Now` of: `ACCOUNT, CARD, INVESTMENTS, LOAN, OTHER, PAYMENT` is correct alphabetically.

If you `REQUIRE` the output to be: `ACCOUNT, CARD, INVESTMENTS, LOAN, PAYMENT, OTHER`

You can assign numerical values to the Enum values like so:

```
public enum ItemCategory 
{
    ACCOUNT = 0, 
    CARD = 1, 
    INVESTMENTS = 2, 
    LOAN = 3, 
    PAYMENT = 4,
    OTHER = 5
}
```

Then when doing the `Sorting`/`Ordering` you can do:

```
var itemList = new List<ItemCategory>
{
    ItemCategory.CARD,
    ItemCategory.ACCOUNT,
    ItemCategory.OTHER,
    ItemCategory.INVESTMENTS,
    ItemCategory.LOAN,
    ItemCategory.PAYMENT
};
        
var sortedList = itemList.OrderBy(i => (int)i).ToList();
```

Then you can iterate through the list and it will be in the following order:

```
ACCOUNT
CARD
INVESTMENTS
LOAN
PAYMENT
OTHER
```

Comment: That is not Kotlin, though, is it?

Comment: It isn't, it's in C#, but the premise is the same, the Author also accepted the answer as it working for them